# If my variable contains quoted globs and I expand it without using double quotes, why do the globs disappear?

Tags: shell

I was trying to use unquoted strings expansions to pass two arguments to tar; the first is the command-line flag `--exclude` and the second contains a `*` character. In an attempt to avoid premature globbing, I tried quoting the `*`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
x="--exclude '*'"
echo tar $x
```

To my surprise, the `'*'` completely disappeared! Here was the output:

```
tar --exclude
```

I understand that I could switch from POSIX shell to Bash and use arrays to avoid this headache. But I still wonder: what the hell was going on with that POSIX shell snippet? Why did it delete the quoted globs? I would have expected that it would leave the quoted part alone, or go all the way and expand the glob. It did neither of those.

Comment: Obligatory links: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are already using `bash` - or at least some non-POSIX options. (Neither `shopt` nor `nullglob` is POSIX.)

Now let's explain what happened.

```
x="--exclude '*'"
echo tar $x
```

The variable `$x` is word-split on whitespace, and the resulting parts given over for globbing. `--exclude` has no wildcard and is left verbatim. `'*'` has no match (unless you have a file name literally starting and ending with a single quote), so because it contains a wildcard and you've set `nullglob` it is removed. The result is

```
tar --exclude
```

Since you are already using `bash` you might as well do it properly,

```
x=('--exclude' '*')
echo tar "${x[@]}"
```

If you want a POSIX solution the best I can offer is to reuse the main argument list:

```
set -- '--exclude' '*'
echo tar "$@"
```

Comment: Shouldn't single-quotes prevent globbing from happening to the * at all? I guess not.  weird.

Comment: @davolfman, no, the single quotes are just data here (when coming from a variable expansion, that is). It's the same as how `a="foo && bar"; echo $a` prints `foo && bar`, instead of using `&&` as an operator. The result of unquoted expansion is word-split and used for globbing only, it doesn't get parsed for shell syntax in general. Note that the opposite would mean that something like `s="ain't so"; echo $s` would cause a syntax error from the unclosed quoted string. But yes, one could think of the way unquoted expansions work as weird.

Comment: Something like `x="--exclude=*"; echo tar "$x"` would also work here, as long as `$x` only contains a single arg to tar. (note I changed the space in the middle to `=` so as _not_ to need splitting)

Comment: I was under a mistaken impression that single quotes prevented all expansion since it prevents variable expansion.  In that case they would have prevented globbing in the echo.

Comment: @davolfman yes and no. Single quotes prevent expansion, but here they were inside a double-quoted string and so not treated by the shell as anything other than a `'` character

Comment: @ChrisDavies So it's not the type of quotes, I've now checked that.  So I guess quotes are handled before the other expansions and as a result the quotes created by the variable expansion are not processed as quotes and get included during filename expansion?

Comment: @davolfman `a='apple'; echo "1.a=$a" '2.a=$a'` Now repeat the process with `a="'apple'"` and `a='"apple"'`. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

For corner cases like this the order of shell expansions in the [Bash Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) is usually the cause of unexpected behavior.  Posix has more-or-less the same behavior but stated less clearly.

Here's what's going on:

You've turn nullglob so globs that fail are empty.

Next you set a variable containing a literal asterisk, and single quotes.

You then echo the contents of the variable and the following things happen:

1. The variable is expanded into text. That text contains a `'*'`
2. The `'*'` is substituted for any file names present, in spite of the single quotes that you'd think would make it a string literal only.  Nullglob turns this into an empty string
3. The command is executed

Comment: Single-quote chars _within a double-quoted string_ are NOT 'consumed'; try `x="it's 'me'!";echo "$x"`

Comment: Yeah this is much weirder and stupider than I thought then.  It looks a lot like nullglob is implemented incorrectly.

Comment: So single quotes prevent variable expansion but double quotes prevent filename expansion?  That's unpleasant

Comment: What makes you think it's incorrect? A value of `'*'` _in a variable_ (not part of the command input) is a glob for filenames that begin and end with singlequote characters; since there (almost certainly) are no such filenames, there is no match and nullglob removes it. Single quotes _in command input not within other quotes_ disable all expansions; double quotes _in command input not within other quotes_ disable brace and tilde expansions, wordsplitting, and globbing (and redirection and process substition) but allow parameter/variable and arithmetic expansions and command substitution. ...

Comment: ... Either kind of quote _within the other kind of quotes_ or in a variable value is just data. (And in doublequotes backslash+doublequote is one doublequote as data.)